# CosmosDB with MongoDB - Getting current database time

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to query Cosmos using Mongo to get the current DateTime of the Database, or any other "fast", or "inexpensive" way to get a central DateTime?

I was using a command in Mongo which can be run in RoboMongo

```
db.runCommand("serverStatus: 1")
```

This would return the current date time of the database along with a lot of other values.:

```
"localTime" : ISODate("2018-02-05T17:24:01.972Z")
```

I ran this same command with Cosmos DB using robomongo and I only get two results back

```
{
    "_t" : "OKMongoResponse",
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I have tried looking for a solution but couldn't find anything related.

Any help would be appreciated :) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to call `db.hostInfo()`, which, among other things, returns the current date+time as seen by the Cosmos DB service. Here's the output I get when running this against one of my Cosmos DB MongoDB API instances:

```
globaldb:PRIMARY> db.hostInfo()
{
    "_t" : "HostInfoResponse",
    "ok" : 1,
    "system" : {
        "currentTime" : ISODate("2018-02-05T23:19:05.588Z"),
        "hostname" : "AzureCosmosDB.APIforMongoDB",
        "cpuAddrSize" : 64,
        "memSizeMB" : 131072,
        "numCores" : 128,
        "cpuArch" : "x86_64",
        "numaEnabled" : true
    },
    "os" : {
        "type" : "Windows",
        "name" : "Microsoft Windows",
        "version" : "Microsoft Windows Server"
    },
    "extra" : {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help David, works perfect!